# Appium explicit wait doesn't work on hybrid app and cannot locate web view elements

Tags: java, selenium, webview, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

Appium driver is not waiting to identify the elements in hybrid app and times out.Then test fails. Here is my java code to test a hybrid app.Here I used TestNG framework. First I switch to web context of the app and make an explicit wait till the element is visible.

```
@BeforeMethod          
public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException
{

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.example.touch");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.example.touch.MainActivity");


    driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

}

@Test
public void LoginTest() {

  java.util.Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();


  for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
     driver.context(contextName);
    }
  }

  try {
      System.out.println("uy");
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {

      }


  WebDriverWait wait;
  wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElementByXPath("*[@id='login-page']####")));



  driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='login-page']####").sendKeys("abc");
  driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='login-page']####").sendKeys("xyz");
  driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='login-button']####").click();
 }

@AfterMethod
public void End() {

  driver.quit();
}
```

This is the error message I get from appium server after running the TestNG test.

> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding *[@id='login-  page']/div[1]/div[5]/div/input using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"Could not find an element using supplied strategy. "}
>   info: [debug] Condition unmet after 1527ms. Timing out.
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.","origValue":"Could not find an element using supplied strategy. "},"sessionId":"51df32dc-3fdf-4b84-95f2-dd020590b861"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/51df32dc-3fdf-4b84-95f2-dd020590b861/element 500 1527.819 ms - 230 
>   info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/51df32dc-3fdf-4b84-95f2-dd020590b861 {}

Comment: Did you try by increasing wait from 60 to 120 or something?

Comment: You should recheck - wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElementByXPath("*[@id='login-page']####"))); Xpath string doesn't contains- //

Comment: @Helping Hands... yes i tried it using 300 for wait but it didn't help.

Comment: @Vvvaib... yes I noted that and did the change like this. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='login-page']#####"))); but the same error mentioned above is coming.

Comment: Then I think you should try with real device or other emulator i.e Genymotion. Because Android default emulator is very slow and causing so many problems.

Comment: I tried it using real device but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check if there is any webview in your app or if it is then is it debuggable? refer https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: +1 to what @PankajKatiyar says. First thing you should do is check that there is really a WEBVIEW* context available. Something like this after your contextName loop would do the trick:
Assert.assertEquals(driver.getContext(), "WEBVIEW_com.example.touch");